# Advanced Where Clause In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an issue with my query in Laravel eloquent, I do not get results when I run the query and the generated query does not seem to be what I expect.

This is the code in controller:

```
$lastUpdate = Input::get('last_update');
$userId = Auth::user()->id;

$eventIds = EventVendor::where('user_id', $userId)
                    ->where('is_active', 1)->get()->lists('event_id');

$events = EventDetails::whereIn('id', $eventIds)
                    ->where(function($query) use ($lastUpdate) {
                        $query->where('created_at', $lastUpdate);
                        $query->orWhere('updated_at', $lastUpdate);
                    })
                    ->where('is_active', 1)
                    ->with("details_sub")
                    ->with("extras")
                    ->with("chargesDiscounts")
                    ->toSql();
```

This is the query that is generated:

```
select * from `mtgh_event_details` 
    where `mtgh_event_details`.`deleted_at` is null 
        and 0 = 1 
        and (`created_at` = ? or `updated_at` = ?) 
        and `is_active` = ?
```

Apart from the `0 = 1` which isn't supposed to be in there I do not see the full query either.

Comment: Is the `0 = 1` actually showing up in your query, or is that something you changed for the question?

Comment: It shows up in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the issue, apparently this part of the query

```
$eventIds = EventVendor::where('user_id', $userId)
                    ->where('is_active', 1)->get()->lists('event_id');
```

Was returning null or an empty list, hence the `0 = 1` in my query.  Also with the help of the other answer I was able to simplify my code a bit so thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

The `0 = 1` is showing up because the query to populate your `$eventIds` is not returning any results, so your `Collection` is empty. If you pass an empty array (or `Collection`) to `whereIn()`, it shortcuts the query by adding in `0 = 1`, since searching `where id in ()` is invalid SQL, and logically searching in an empty set will always return no results anyway. This shortcut was added in 4.2.17 with [this pull request](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/6986).

As for the rest of the query, everything looks normal to me. The `with()` statements are setting up eager loading, which uses separate SQL statements; it does not use joins.

So, since you have three `with()` statements, you will actually be running four separate queries, one to get your `EventDetails`, and then one each to load your `details_sub`, `extras`, and `chargesDiscounts` for the loaded event details.

Since they are separate queries, they will not show up in the `toSql()` output.

---

Other notes:

- When getting the event ids, you don't need to call `->get()->lists()`, you can simply call `->lists()` on the query. If you call `get()` first, it will load the full objects into a `Collection`, and then you're calling `lists()` on the `Collection`. You can avoid loading the full `Collection` in the first place by just calling `lists()` on the query itself.
- Assuming you have the relationships setup, you can avoid the initial query to get the ids in the first place. You can use the [`whereHas()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) instead. Your query would look like:

  ```
  $lastUpdate = Input::get('last_update');
  $userId = Auth::user()->id;

  // assumes a relationship named 'vendor'
  $events = EventDetails::whereHas('vendor', function($query) use ($userId) {
              // $query is query for the EventVendors
              $query->where('user_id', $userId)->where('is_active', 1)
          })
          ->where(function($query) use ($lastUpdate) {
              $query->where('created_at', $lastUpdate);
              $query->orWhere('updated_at', $lastUpdate);
          })
          ->where('is_active', 1)
          ->with("details_sub")
          ->with("extras")
          ->with("chargesDiscounts")
          ->toSql();
  ```

Comment: user3718908 I have updated my answer to provide some information regarding your 0 = 1 issue.